Should we avoid calling Spring Batch Cron Job through Web Request?
Context
I have a Spring Batch Cron Job that works well and starts every day at 9 AM.
The role of this job is to consume Kafka messages sent from another application and then save them into its own database.
The Problem
The developpers of the other application are not sure that their sending of Kafka messages will be finished by 9 AM every day.
So they would like to be able to trigger the launch of this job immediately after their sending batch is terminated.
Many solutions were suggested like VTOM calls, or triggering the job from web requests
but One Tech Lead said it wasn't a good practice in the company, and that he prefers Cron Job with static schedule time.
He wants to avoid a pod for the web app and pods for Cron Jobs in Openshift.
Questions
Are there any best practices for handling this use-case ?
Examples:

Listening to a Kafka event topic @KafkaListener that sends a messages
when the sending batch is terminated and then we consumes messages
from the topic that contains data to read
Launching job only from web requests (No more schedule time by default)
Other solutions ?


I believe you should explain why you have to wait for all messages to be present in the queue before start processing messages. BR

Hello @RoarS thanks for your reply, Well actually it's just that our CronJob consumes all the Kafka messages in less than 3 minutes. So if the other service hasn't finished sending, the job might finish before all the messages are sent. Among the question I wrote that maybe using KafkaListener instead of a CronJob might be the best solution. What do you think ? Thanks !

I would go for this: "that maybe using KafkaListener instead of a CronJob might be the best solution". We were using this strategy with GCP Pub/Sub in a recent project with success. BR

Thanks again @RoarS. In my case I would like to keep my Spring Batch job as it is because performances are good, data are checked, and we have skip Policy). I'm thinking of the other team keeps sending their data in the current topic, but as soon as all their data are sent, they send another message in another event topic (i.e: a message "All data sent"). My app listens to this other topic and when receiving this message, launch the Spring Batch job. So I think there will be 2 corresponding pods on Openshift. Do you see any with that system ? Thanks again
